# (Welcome Page) Search People Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

I am trying to add page in SharePoint Online but page layout **(Welcome Page) Search People**  is not showing up among the options.

Is it some SharePoint Feature that I need to activate to get the page layout?

Comment: I have my welcome page Search people set up but it doesn't pull anything in. I am trying to set up a company directory that is searchable but I am not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate the following site collection feature:

**Search Server Web Parts and Templates**
This feature will add the Search Server Web Parts and Display Templates to your site. Search will work on most sites without this feature being activated, but if you get a message about missing templates when searching, then activate this feature.

The layout should be available after you activate this. If not, check the **Page layouts and site templates** page under site settings. The site could be configured to only use certain page layouts.

-Hope it helps

Comment: I didn't found the exact match for **Search Server Web Parts and Templates Features** in site feature !!     but yes I found **Search Config Template Feature**...   are the both same ?

Comment: You are looking at "Site Features" not "Site Collection Features"...

Comment: Check answer given by Cherry Wang MSFT Support  on https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/229652

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer is incorrect. The Site Collection feature SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features needs to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rodirgo, your suggestion helped.

and in the mean time I get another workaround:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/229652.aspx

this link also provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enable the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature.