# welcome page search results missing after enabling features

Tags: 2016, feature, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-standard

I am trying to get the welcome page search results page to display when I am trying to add a new page. I have followed the instructions from [(Welcome Page) Search People Page Layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138785/welcome-page-search-people-page-layout) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0a8679b4-71c7-447f-a21d-cb36296fb9b4/error-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-while-activating-manage-site-features-in?forum=appsforsharepoint). I am not sure if I am missing another feature or not. I currently have `Search Server Web Parts and Templates`, `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure`, and `SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features` active from the site collection features. Under the site features I have `SharePoint Server Publishing`, `Search Config Data Content Types` and `SharePoint Server Standard Site features` enabled. Am I missing a feature?